# VALORANT on Steam

Tags: steam, valorant

Has Riot Games ever said anything about putting VALORANT on Steam? Have there ever been any rumours about doing so? If so, when was this, and what was said?

I know VALORANT is available on Windows, which is what I play it on, but it's not on other OSs (to my knowledge).

Recently, I think, there were some rumours about putting VALORANT on Linux (pretty sure there's a YouTube video about it)... I'm not sure how true that it, considering Linux is much less popular than other OSs (at least, I think it is).

---

Also, have they ever said anything about why it's not on Steam, considering they would be able to greatly expand their playerbase if it was?

---

I'm sorry if this isn't on topic here, but I've already moved it to Game Dev/Design SE after it was closed and someone told I should, and then had the question closed over there because, guess what - they said I should put it here.

Comment: Riot uses its own launcher for their multiplayer games, so it's about as likely as Blizzard putting their games on Steam.

Comment: Like Diablo 4 on Steam you mean? ;)

Comment: Blizzard already has their game on other platform, and so do Riot - except its not Steam unlike Blizzard, but Microsoft Store.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** No, *Valorant* isn't coming on steam anytime soon, and it probably also isn't getting Linux support in the near future.

AFAIK, Riot Games has never officially said anything about putting *Valorant* on Steam. And well rumors spread all the time, but mostly they're baseless.

*Valorant* uses their own kernel level anti-cheat software, Vanguard, which is basically a kind of driver that runs at boot to prevent any kind of cheat system to start, and it is really not possible to play *Valorant* on any other operating system other than Windows unless Riot Games itself releases *Valorant* for other platforms. Sure, you can try using a VM, but yet again, you can only run Vanguard on your native machine, not a VM.